# SSRS 2008 Filtering Multi-Value Parameter for Display in Report Header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a multi-value parameter (Param_Locations) from which a user can select multiple service locations (e.g. LocationA, LocationA Optical Shop, LocationB, LocationB Optical Shop, ...). The selection of these locations is important for the dataset I will be generating. I am then able to display the selected locations in the header of the report using: =Join(Parameters!Param_Locations.Label).

The issue I have is that I want to filter out any location that has the word "Optical" in the Label. I do not want those locations to show in the report header even though they may have been selected from the drop-down selection list.

I have tried using the Filter() function to no avail. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards!
Babak C
Phoenix, AZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct to try the filter method.  I tested the below code successfully in SQL Server 2012 SP1.

```
=Join(Filter(Parameters!Param_Locations.Label, "Optical Shop", False), ", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use Custom Code to do this; it's just slightly too complex to try and do with the native functions but you can loop through the parameter labels pretty easily in Custom Code:

```
Public Function ShowParameterValues(ByVal parameter as Parameter) as String

  Dim s as String 

  For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1

    If InStr(CStr(parameter.Label(i)), "Optical") = 0
      s = s + CStr(parameter.Label(i)) + ", " 
    End If

  Next

  s = Mid(s, 1, Len(s) - 2)

  Return s

End Function
```

Call the function like this in the report when you want to display the filtered parameter labels:

```
=Code.ShowParameterValues(Parameters!Param_Locations)
```

See [Using Custom Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for more details.